# How do I calculate years until graduation for a user's input?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I would like to program something where the user inputs their graduation year (i.e 2032) and it would print out "You will graduate in 12 years." However with the code I have created, it only works for graduation years 2020 through 2029, not years after 2029.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NameGames {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner one = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter graduation year: ");
   int gradYear = one.nextInt();
   
   System.out.println("You will graduate in " + untilGrad(gradYear) + " years.");
   }

   public static int untilGrad(int gradYear) {
      return (gradYear % 10);
   }
}
```

Comment: Of course it only works until 2029. The real way to do it is to subtract the gradYear from the current year.

Comment: Thank you so much, forgot I could just make an int variable called currentYear and subtract it from gradYear.

Comment: Don't worry :). We all learn in different ways :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `untilGrad` method should be;

```
int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
return gradYear-year;
```

Your goal is to find the number of years until their graduation year. This involves getting the current year via `Calendar`.